# Freys elliptic curves and Hilbert spaces?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, hilbert-spaces

Consider the Frey-Hellegouarch curve given $a,b$ positive rational numbers:

$$y^2= x\left(x-\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}\right)\left(x+\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}\right)$$

The j-invariant is given by:

$$j(a,b) = \frac{16^2(a^2+ab+b^2)^3}{a^2b^2(a+b)^2}$$

It seems that:

$$\frac{1}{j(a,b)}$$

is positive definite and hence can be used to embedd in a reproducing kernel Hilbert space.

Notice that all points lie on a sphere in this Hilbert space.

I have plotted points of this Hilbert space using the Cholesky decomposition, and it seems that all this points define an elliptic curve (my guess is it is the Frey Curve $y^2=x(x-1)(x+1)$):

[Example plots in Sagemath](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJydVU1v4jAQvfMrIvViB4fEVNpdrZZTteqpqGiPUYicYMCNSYwTKPTX79gOIWnpqtocgj0fb2Zens2Kr7215uc0P-gjR4xk-OfIg0fz5qBL77eUQjUif7DuOCIoCxgON_nKxpKIBMzPur3vT0mU4NFoBbgvLx_xEP22nIb0-_SHj9hyOobkcbac4uV9aPY-rMExzjDYWhjNc6F0lTOZ3kKkYWt10UXxMeTSXWiR_amLFHVV51zytNGClRtppydFMRsUbJE2bLdj3sxjeVWjtkZY73XjNgz78JuBEbo28VuIrUWJbB6elMiZ7x7B_qiZ2oq8bm0STDEwGyUkpvZtarhEcsUAu4lJLjjjmSdFyZHE_VGlm22l2eu7uejNuSSF6p8wQR3yjZZ71WnPkgudQzKCPjG5OCY1b1JWK543qWaNqNDVs61eAdG1zHcZX61S3grOCTJVlSibVJTpn3v03PZ8IEdo6bk_9hHQK43iQ4jo-AC6OoJ-yHGwQ8F103cklw42vHk25WDKlhz7aRzjc1jSyC7XlfaEJ0pPA1kcBff-nNDIn7dZtkXDqk8nUTjvbGLtHXx0GFMM74DiX9E13jx5VTaiPPDOaKa0EhukXcVknm4h5YQpxcsV-gKTCCjE2MP_nR1c0y_CA-VZvqSoG-SYoUAL9I3BMeGnxsDHiwWC-wPeGbZEMkMkJJp15tYJ7iGBepCUgPEElh0DhZ5QHHeHvo-RDECIFuVmtljg0Z2CZYOeYDUAaY_xVyAeIO9pkm8ryevijDrMh4muXkEv7eUDp-vF6LxWW65b0pAiekZbbRgVSV4ihW-pV8UicZeKDlQ8D2gC8nwvt4iAAyfvKlbwZQpXihSz6e1ye9iqWxKeB0VPvDbs1iR7gNeDzveui7qBoGrjLom0zRWVKexgT-RM3rrqw7HRCU5j8IbJ2f0aMpUyJ284nCaU3Ds6tGn9wn0CwgOlpEpWDYr_0YpNVSZVqQR3t4_N6_0Hgmpxz2snj9VnydbduzlaV__Cg6__F-T1KhM=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)
(it takes a few minutes to do the computation)

My conjecture is, that the group of poisitive rational points operates on $\phi(a)$ where $\phi$ is an embedding to the reproducing Hilbert space, via:

$$q \cdot \phi(a) = \phi(qa)$$

This group operation has one orbit, and I suspect that this orbit "defines" the Frey elliptic curve $y^2=x(x+1)(x-1)$, but I am not sure about this.

Furthermore for two distinct $a,b$ we should have that

$\phi(a),\phi(b)$ somehow define the Frey curve:

$$y^2= x\left(x-\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}\right)\left(x+\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}\right)$$

Of course this all is not precise, since if it was, I would know how to do the constructions and would not ask.

Is there an explanation for this, or given distinct $a,b$ a construction from the Hilbert space to the Frey elliptic curve?

Thanks for your help!

(Related question: [Discriminant of elliptic curve (Frey-Hellegouarch), j-invariant and positive definite kernels, similarities?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361894/discriminant-of-elliptic-curve-frey-hellegouarch-j-invariant-and-positive-def))